# wcf iis private msmq

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq

I have a wcf service hosted in iis.
I have many clients connected to it via basicHttpBinding.

On the same server I also have other service that is doing the business logic.
The business service puts the messages on local private queue. The wcf service in a separate thread waits for a change in the private queue and if it sees new message it takes and remembers the message.

Everything works as expected. The business server puts the message on the private queue and the wcf service takes the message and serves the clients.

The problem begins when I restart the server.
Then the clients does not receive the data they expect.
If I restart the iis everything goes to normal.

Can someone tell me what could be the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that the iis service is starting before the business service, you could establish a dependency so that the business service will always start before the iis service.